# Multiple inference rules aligned

Tags: alignment, proof-package, bussproofs, logicproof

I'm trying to write several inference rules aligned like this but I've run into some difficulties and haven't found a suitable way to do it.

Any ideas ?

Thanks for your help.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arrays separated by whatever space you choose.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{c}
A \\
(\lnot A \lor C)\\ \hline
C
\end{array}\qquad
%
\begin{array}{c}
A \\
(\lnot A \lor C)\\ \hline
C
\end{array}\qquad
%
\begin{array}{c}
A \\
(\lnot A \lor C)\\ \hline
C
\end{array}\qquad
%
\begin{array}{c}
A \\
(\lnot A \lor C)\\ \hline
C
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```